# The escape character `\` in bracket expression

Tags: bash, grep

I read such an example which excerpted from an instruction,
and intend to examine `\` in `^[-[:alnum:]\._]+$`

```
# is input a valid filename?
read -p "Enter a single item > "
if [[ "$REPLY" =~ ^[-[:alnum:]\._]+$ ]]; then
    echo "'$REPLY' is a valid filename."
else
    echo "The string '$REPLY' is not a valid filename."
fi
```

check the bracket expression by feeding some combinations.

```
$ bash read_validate.sh
Enter a single item > test.tst.
'test.tst.' is a valid filename.'
#test `\`
$ bash read_validate.sh
Enter a single item > test\\tst
The string 'test\tst' is not a valid filename.
```

When i remove the escape `\` from `^[-[:alnum:]\._]+$`, to be `^[-[:alnum:]._]+$`

```
$ bash read_validate.sh
Enter a single item > test.tst
'test.tst' is a valid filename.
# to assert that dot is not the any character sign.
$ bash read_validate.sh
Enter a single item > test*tst
The string 'test*tst' is not a valid filename.
# codes run properly.
```

It seems not necessary to insert escape `\` to the pattern.

Is that right?
I cannot make sure if  omit some key points about the bracket expression and escape character?

Comment: Inside bracket expression you don't need to escape dot and many other regex meta characters. So `^[-[:alnum:]._]+$` and `^[-[:alnum:]\._]+$` are same.

Comment: excluding `\\`, right?

Comment: Yes excluding \ and `-` (if hyphen appears in middle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash uses [Extended Regular Expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05). Quoting the standard:

> The special characters '.', '*', '[', and '\' (period, asterisk, left-bracket, and backslash, respectively) shall lose their special meaning within a bracket expression.

So inside `[ ]`, they don't need to be escaped.

The situation is made slightly more complicated by the fact that Bash processes backslashes in your string:

```
$ set -x
$ [[ '\' =~ [\.] ]] && echo yes
+ [[ \ =~ [.] ]]                # look, no backslash!
```

So the recommended way to use regular expressions is to set a shell variable:

```
$ re='[\.]'
+ re='[\.]'
$ [[ '\' =~ $re ]] && echo yes
+ [[ \ =~ [\.] ]]               # backslash preserved!
+ echo yes
yes
```

Comment: but in `[[ "$REPLY" =~ ^[-[:alnum:]\._]+$ ]]`, \ does not lose its special meaning, I add the test to my question.

Comment: It can't hurt to escape a backslash in a character class (since `[aa.]` is the same as `[a.]`, so `[\.]` should be the same as `[\\.]`).  In some languages, the backslash retains its ability to act as an escape in character classes (for example, sometimes the _only_ way to match a backspace character is when it is escaped in a character class as `[\b]` since some regex interpreters consider it a word break indicator), so it's always safer to add the second one.